# How to remove all default permissions from a Necessitas Android app?

Tags: android, qt, android-permissions, qt-necessitas

Necessitas applications for Android seem to have three permissions enabled by default:

```
- Storage
     modify/delete SD card contents
- Network communication
     full internet access
- Phone calls
     read phone state and identity
```

I want to remove them. I already tried searching in all of my project's files for `uses-permission` and I've found and deleted these two lines from `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

However, after deleting the lines now my Necessitas app still needs two permissions:

```
- Storage
     modify/delete SD card contents
- Phone calls
     read phone state and identity
```

It seems I've gotten rid of only the network permission. How do I get rid of all three?

Answer (score 1):

All the permissions required for the app are listed in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, e.g

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

You can delete from your manifest if they are not needed. What other permissions are in your Manifest?

But, if your application requires the permissions that you have deleted to run, you'll get an Exception. So you would need to check that your app doesnt need the deleted permissions

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've already deleted all the permissions from `AndroidManifest.xml`, but the app still asks for permissions when installing, so I'm a bit stumped. Do you think the Necessitas framework is compiling the permissions into my app despite what I have in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: As far as I understand, you can set the permissions required in your QTCreator project window. YOur manifest would be generated automatically

Answer (score 1):

The permission `Phone calls` disappears when I publish my app developed with Necessitas to Google Play, I don't know why :P

The permission `Storage` is still on and my app needs it.

Comment: Hmmm, good to know, but I'd still like to know why this happens. I have no permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Do you think Necessitas adds the permissions when we compile, regardless of what we have in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: @trusktr Hi, I haven't inspected the source code, can only guess Necessitas or [ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) generates a default `AndroidManifest.xml` if it doesn't exist. [The active developers](http://necessitas.kde.org/people.php) of Necesitas should know the details.

Answer (score 0):

read carefully inside the manifest file:

```
<!-- The following comment will be replaced upon deployment with default permissions based on the dependencies of the application.
     Remove the comment if you do not require these default permissions. -->
<!-- %%INSERT_PERMISSIONS -->
```